# Android Studio: How to Create a Class to Override the OnInterceptTouchEvent for a Parent Layout then pass events onto child elements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, touch

I need to Intercept all the touch events for the parent layout (which is a Constraint Layout ) So i am able to swipe the layout onto the screen as half the layout is hidden halfway down at the bottom of the screen and once it has reached near the top of the screen it locks in place and then the user is able to scroll through everything inside the Layout.

Examples of what exactly i want to learn and achieve are:
(The object at the bottom which you are able to swipe up and get more information)

- Apple Maps
- Disney Land Paris App

I have tried to look at resources but cant find exactly what i need. if it is anyway possible to direct me to resources to help someone who is new to developing in Android Studio and for Touche Events.

Comment: You implement it and redirect it to whatever views you want

Comment: @Josh_1234 It's called https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html# You can try to search by keywords: "android bottomsheet behavior". This is looks like what you search: https://medium.com/@emrullahluleci/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066